# Querying on XML issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, casting, ssms

I've been using this query for over a year now. It works perfectly fine when using this on a UTF-8 XML.

The column `XML` is currently of type `NVARCHAR(MAX)` so I have to cast it to `XML` first.

```
SELECT REPLACE(
  XML,
  '<MetaData04></MetaData04>',
  '<MetaData04>' + cast([XML] as XML).query(N'/BOM/BO/Documents/NumAtCard').value('.', 'varchar(30)') + '</MetaData04>'
) 
FROM table1 
WHERE state = 1
```

Now this works perfectly on this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BOM>
  <BO>
    <Documents>
      <NumAtCard>1234</NumAtCard>
      <MetaData04>test</MetaData04>
    </Documents>
  </BO>
</BOM>
```

But not on this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<BOM>
  <BO>
    <Documents>
      <Field Name="NumAtCard" Multi="No">
        <Value>1234</Value>
      </Field>
      <Field Name="MetaData04" Multi="No">
        <Value>test</Value>
      </Field>  
    </Documents>
  </BO>
</BOM>
```

Is there a way to `.query` on this ISO-8859-1 XML?

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 2017.

Thanks in advance, Koen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/BOM/BO/Documents/NumAtCard` needs to be changed to

```
/BOM/BO/Documents/Field[@Name="NumAtCard"]/Value
```

Comment: Perfect, Thanks Choroba! You made my day!